# Is panda's DataFrame suitable for this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let's depict my scenario:

I'm trying to make an analysis on several APIs for a given set of samples. Thus, in the end, I'm picturing this as follows in my mind:

A 2D table where each row is the name of each sample, and where each column is the name of each API. On each of this table, I will end up having a variable number of pairs key-value (for instance, 'dog':0.9). So let's put a simple example

```
________________________________________________________________________
|row/column |   API 1      |   API 2      |   API  3     |   API 4     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|sample1    |{'dog':0.9,   |{'cat':0.3,   |{'dog':0.7,   |{'cat':0.2,  |
|           |'animal': 0.8}|'mammal':0.4} |'mammal':0.3} |'animal':0.9}|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|sample2    |{'sun':0.6,   |{'sun':0.7,   |{'wind':0.5,  |{'sun':0.1,  |
|           |'beach': 0.3} |'water':0.7}  |'water':0.2}  |'wind':0.3}  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|sample3    |{'tenis':0.9, |{'court':0.3, |{'court':0.7, |{'ball':0.2, |
|           |'ball': 0.8}  |'player':0.4} |'tennis':0.3} |'court':0.9} | 
________________________________________________________________________
```

And so on..

The number of elements will not be 2 always...it can be from 0 to N, but normally will never be more than 3-4 tags.

That said, what I want to do with this data afterwards are simple calculation like:

- Number of occurrences in all APIs
- Maximum-Miminum scores
- Tags appearing only in an API

Nothing really complicated as you can see.

My question is, being a total noob with pandas...is DataFrame a good approach? Is this arrangement of data ok or should it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would want to use a [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) where the `index` levels contain a `sample_id` and the `api_id`, and then you have two columns containing the `tag` and the associated `value`. Then you can use easily run your stats using `.groupby(level='api_id').value.max()`, for instance.

This could look as follows:

```
                   tag  value
sample_id api_id             
1         1       tag1      1
2         1       tag2      2
3         1       tag3      3
4         2       tag1      1
5         2       tag2      2
6         2       tag3      3
7         2       tag4      1
8         2       tag5      2
9         2       tag6      3
10        3       tag1      1
11        3       tag2      2
12        3       tag3      3
13        3       tag4      1
14        3       tag5      2
15        4       tag1      3
```

Comment: Hello Stefan, thanks for the link, I'm a bit confused tough...does MultiIndex requires to have same lenght array for constructing? Or they can have variable lenght?

Comment: You mean different arrays of tag:value per API? See example, since `api_id` would be part of the `MultiIndex`, you could be flexible.

Comment: Indeed, I can have more than one tag per sample-api, does this still apply? Thanks for the example, by the way :)

Comment: Sure. First, the `MultiIndex` values don't have to be unique, and there's nothing from preventing you from adding an additional `id` column if you get multiple `tag-value` pairs for a `sample_id - api_id` combination. Unique values help with some features that require a sorted index, see docs.